# Why pointer is not null after free() (no copy pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, nullable

I use only main() function. Not copying any pointer.
Why free() function not get NULL value?
Whay I can check my wariable is full or empty?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int *e = NULL;

 printf("before e=%p\n",(void *)e);
 e = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *e = 7;
 printf("after,  e=%p\n",(void *)e);
 if(e == NULL) { printf("Problemy z pamięcia\n"); return 0; }
 printf(" value = %d\n",*e);

 free(e);
 printf("after free,  e=%p\n",(void *)e);
 if(e == NULL) printf("is NULL\n");

return 1;
}
```

result

```
before e=0
after,  e=464027a0
 value = 7
after free,  e=0x7f82464027a0
```

why if(e==NULL) is not true? How do it?

Comment: Why should it get a NULL value?

Comment: because i need check it is 'e' release free() or not an my program, after free(). Sometimes i use free or not. Information about 'e' is random, empty is important for me after next lines

Comment: `free` just frees the memory associated with the pointer. It does not set the variables value to NULL. You need to do that manually.

Comment: @AlojzyDrabina - Why do you think you need to check? Do you check that the compiler does arithmetic correctly? Just don't leak memory, and trust free.

Comment: @StoryTeller no my algorithm is more complicatet than this example

Comment: All the more reason to be diligent and not leak memory. You are looking for a language/library solution to what is essentially a design/programming issue.

Answer (score 4):

Because C has a [call-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) policy and [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) is a standard function. Every function call is not modifying its arguments, because formal parameters hold a *copy* of the argument passed at the call.

In practice, you could use the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and systematically do

```
  free(e), e = NULL;
```

However, using a pointer (value) after it has been `free`-d is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB, so learn more about it.

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` [if](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and learn to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). You could use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [address sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), since they are very helpful to hunt bugs such as [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)s or [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)s.

BTW, your code is wrong. You don't test against failure of [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (your `if(e == NULL)` is too late, and the preceding  `*e = 7;` is likely to get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when `malloc` has failed) , and you really should code at least something like:

```
 e = malloc(sizeof(int));
 if (!e) { perror("malloc e"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

The `!e` above could be replaced by `e==NULL` for readability.

Comment: `free(e), e = NULL`. Looks like a nice way of doing it.